# Using variable to echo set data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't think of how to do this in my head so I would like someone to lay this out for me. What I am trying to do is allow a user to set a custom greeting for a email using a variable. So for example, in the body of the email, they'll place "$greeting" which will echo out a random greeting they set {'hey', 'hello', 'hi'}.

can someone explain how I would achieve this?

Comment: you mean that your users write "$greeting" and you should later convert this to i.e. 'hey'? or to a random version among the ones you mentioned?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 2):

you will need to use something like https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

its the cleanest way, regex is not the way to do it. that would allow you to do something like

hi {user.name}, ... in the mail or any other vars that need to be customized

Answer (score 1):

define your possible greetings in an array

```
$greetings = array('hey', 'hello', 'hi');
```

echo out a random one

```
echo $greetings[array_rand($greetings)];
```

or

```
shuffle($greetings);
echo $greetings[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask the user to supply a comma seperated list of greetings in a text input:

```
hey, hello, hi
```

You can then explode the greetings via , then trim the whitespace (or the other way around probably)

Then allow them to put the $greeting in the message and use array_rand to pick a random one

```
$input = 'hi, heya, morning!';
$greetings = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $input));
$key = array_rand($greetings);
echo $greetings[$key];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would I check if they input $greeting?

Comment: You can check whether they entered $greeting into the email body with a simple strpos(). If you want to check they entered a comma delimited list of greetings use $_POST.  if ( ! empty($_POST['greeting'])) {   }

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe is what you want to do:

```
$userText="A user wants to send a greeting: \$greeting";
echo $userText;
echo "<br/><br/>";

$valArray=array("Hey","Hello","Ciao");

$newText=str_replace("\$greeting",$valArray[array_rand($valArray)],$userText);
echo $newText;
```